# ¿Cómo agregar reconocimiento UTF-8 a mi encriptador/desencriptador?

Tags: java

Tengo un programa que lee unos archivos txt hace ciertas cosas y los guarda en otro txt en otro lugar. Funciona 10 puntos. (El contenido del txt tiene lenguaje ruso.)
Hasta ahí bárbaro.

Si hago el mismo proceso, pero en el medio le agrego un encriptador, encripta todo, cuando lo voy a desencriptar, no desencripta todo, claramente está fallando con las palabras rusas, seguro porque los txts están en UTF-8.

Este encriptador/desencriptador, lo conseguí por Internet.(soy nuevo en java, apenas unos meses). 
Me sirve para lo que lo necesito, excepto por lo de los caracteres que estoy teniendo problema.

Como puedo corregir esto?

Este es al desencriptador/encriptador:

```
public String encriptar(String texto,String clave)
    {
        int tamtext=texto.length();
        int tamclav=clave.length();
        int temp,p=0;
        String encriptado="";
    /* Se crea un array de enteros que contendran los numeros que
       corresponde a los caracteres en Ascii de los String Texto y la Clave */

        int textoAscii[]= new int[tamtext];
        int claveAscii[]= new int[tamclav];

    /* Se guardan los caracteres de cada String en
       numeros correspondientes al Ascii           */
        for(int i=0;i<tamtext;i++)
          textoAscii[i] = texto.charAt(i);

        for(int i=0;i<tamclav;i++)
          claveAscii[i] = clave.charAt(i);

        //Se procede al ENCRIPTADO
       for(int i=0;i<tamtext;i++){
         p++;

         if(p >= tamclav)
          p=0;

         temp =textoAscii[i]+claveAscii[p];

         if (temp > 255)
         temp=temp-255;

         encriptado = encriptado + (char)temp;
        }

     return encriptado;
    }

    public String desencriptar(String texto,String clave){
        int tamtext=texto.length();
        int tamclav=clave.length();
        int temp,p=0;
        String desencriptado="";
    /* Se crea un array de enteros que contendran los numeros que
       corresponde a los caracteres en Ascii de los String Texto y la Clave */

        int textoAscii[]= new int[tamtext];
        int claveAscii[]= new int[tamclav];

    /* Se guardan los caracteres de cada String en
       numeros correspondientes al Ascii           */
        for(int i=0;i<tamtext;i++)
          textoAscii[i] = texto.charAt(i);

        for(int i=0;i<tamclav;i++)
          claveAscii[i] = clave.charAt(i);

        //Se procede al DESENCRIPTADO
        for(int i=0;i<tamtext;i++)
        {
         p++;

          if(p>=tamclav)
          p=0;

         temp=textoAscii[i]-claveAscii[p];

         if (temp < 0)
         temp=temp+256;

         desencriptado=desencriptado + (char)temp;
        }
     return desencriptado;
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Es como trabajar con los caracteres del español, como eñes y acentos, tendrías que tratar los textos antes de encriptarlos. Busca usos de la clase *Normalize* si quieres hacerlo sin librerías, sino lo más facil usar *StringUtils* de Apache commons: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: Pero si funciona bien sin problemas en pasar los caracteres de un txt a otro analizando linea por linea, se pierde cuando lo encripto, creo que en la encriptacion está el problema en no reconocer los caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que un `char` no es exactamente un carácter.

Los `char` son *code-points* de UTF-8. Muchos *code-points* representan directamente un carácter (p.ej. los caracteres ASCII o del alfabeto latino) pero muchos otros símbolos se representan mediante la combinación de dos *code-points*. En estas combinaciones, el primer *code-point* corresponde a un rango de valores que sirve para indicar que no es un carácter por si mismo.

Tu código ignora todo esto y solo trata los *code-points* como números. Pero al cambiarlos pueden no representar lo mismo, y al convertir de nuevo en `String` (o más probablemente, al escribir o leer el archivo), la conversión de los bytes a la representación interna del String puede afectar a algunos de los valores modificados.

La solución (que recomiendo para cualquier método que quiera "encriptar" algo) es trabajar la encriptación sobre los bytes, no sobre los `char`. Obtén los bytes del `String` original, "encriptalos", **pero no vuelvas a trabajar con Strings**. Guarda los bytes en un fichero binario, recupera los bytes como un `byte[]`, y solo después de invertir la "encriptación" vuelve a montar el `String`.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76, así lo había pensado a la primera. Pero soy nuevo en esto y todavia no se como construir eso, ahora estoy viajando, cuando llegue me pondre a buscar, pero de esas casualidades tienes algun encriptador/desencriptador que me pueda servir? Facil para mi? Porque estuve buscando antes y encontraba unicamente codigo en el que creaba una ventana etc, y yo necesito esto para un programa interno, no puedo usar programa con ventana aparte..(tiene que ser como privado de la aplicacion)

Comment: Java tiene la *Java Criptograhpy API* (JCA) ya instalada, y hay muchos tutoriales y ejemplos. De todas formas, si es para una aplicación real, deberías tener claro cuáles son tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76, lo que sucede es que si bien es para una App, tampoco es la GRAN cosa, es simplemente para facilitar una tarea... lo que sucede que los archivos que quiero encriptar son por cuestiones de que eso si me costo mucho trabajo, como para regalarlo así nomas, entonces prefiero que vayan encriptados los archivos y el programa desencripte y use los archivos y luego de el resultado final. Nada del otro mundo, por eso que un encriptador sencillo me es funcional.

Comment: Lo hice con bytes, quedó de maravilla, gracias por la sugerencia.